# IIS 401.3 error for mp4 files

Tags: iis-6

I have a web application which contains a virtual directory for videos. When ever user uploads a videos my automated programe creates mp4 version of that file. My virtual directory is using integrated windows auth. and my .wmv and .mp4 files are in the same folder.

When i am trying to access .mp4 version of the video it is showing me this error.

```
"HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to an ACL set on the    requested resource."
```

At the same time when i access the .wmv file format it is working fine. can any one help me with this.

thanks

Comment: a) You're stating that accessing the .wmv through the browser is fine? In other words, IUSR has the proper ACLs set for that directory?
b) .wmv and .mp4 are located in the same directory?

Answer (score 2):

Add a MIME type for `.mp4` extension in IIS configuration. I *think* that's the problem.

Comment: Likely the issue if indeed we're understanding the question (i.e. location of each file type, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved it with giving Read access to NETWORK SERVICE on required video file